# Interpreting optimal tableau in manufacturing

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

[image]

---

[image]

---

What I tried:

---

3a1 Make $c_3$ greater than the current $z_3$ so any value greater than 20/3?

---

3a2 I just do EROs to make the $x_3$ column into $[0, 0, 1]^T$ ?

---

3b $c_1 \ge 10$? idk

---

3c If we have 630 instead of 600, then I think (instead of re-solving), I think we make use of:

$z' = z + (z_j - c_j)(x_j)$

?

How can I approach this?

---

3d I think of rewriting the LP problem with $x_3=10$:

$$z=10x_1+6x_2$$

s.t.

$$x_1 + x_2 (+ x_4) \le (=) 90$$

$$5x_1 + 2x_2 (+ x_5) \le (=) 275$$

$$x_1 + x_2 (+ x_6) \le (=) 120$$

If asked only for change in obj function value then, we can just do this I believe:

$z' = z + (z_j - c_j)(x_j) = 2200/3 + (8/3)(10)$

Is that right?

---

3e $\begin{bmatrix}
6\\ 
10\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
4\\ 
3
\end{bmatrix}$?

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You are correct, you need $$c_3>20/3$$

b) In the optimal tableau, replace $c_1=10$ by $10+\Delta$, and compute the new reduced costs $z_j-c_j$. You want them to remain positive in order for the tableau to remain optimal, and this gives you
$$
-4<\Delta<5\quad \Rightarrow\quad 6<c_1<15
$$

c) Replace $600$ by $600+30$ in the second constraint. The extra $30$ will be processed like $x_5$, so you will get an additional $30z_{x_5}$ in your objective function, in other words the objective function is increased by 20 units:
$$
z'=z+20
$$

d) You are almost correct, but this will decrease the objective function:
$$
z'=z-\frac{8}{3}10
$$

Comment: Hey again Kuifje. Thanks a million! ^-^ 3a2 Any thoughts on this? 3c Why is the extra 30 processed like $x_5$? d Should my formula have been $z' = z -(z_j - c_j)(x_j)$

Comment: For 3a2, you need to perform a simplex pivot with entering variable $x_3$.   For 3c, the extra $30$ is processed like $x_5$ because $x_5$ has a column that equals $(0,1,0)$ in the initial tableau, and adding $30$ to $600$ is like adding a column $30(0,1,0)=30x_5$ to the RHS in the initial tableau. So both columns will be processed the same way. For 3d, yes, the formula is $z'=z+(c_j-z_j)x_j$.

Comment: THANKS. And 3e please? ^-^

Comment: You need to add a column $(1,4,3)$  in the initial tableau with profit $c_4$. Find the resulting column in the final tableau, and compute the reduced cost $c_4-z_4$. The new product is worth producing is the reduced cost is strictly positive.

Comment: Re-solve? How sure are you? I think the point of sensitivity analysis is to not re-solve anything

Comment: I never said re-solve :) I said find the resulting column. You can do this simply by noticing  $(1,4,3)=(1,0,0)+4(0,1,0)+3(0,0,1)$…so $(1,0,0)$ is processed like the $x_4$ column, etc.

Comment: Kuifje, so the final column is now $1*(5/3,-2/3,-2)+4*(-1/6,1/6,0)+3*(0,0,1) $?

Comment: Kuifje, I think you mean $z_{x_5} - c_{x_5}$ and not $z_{x_5}$ (though they happen to be equal) ?

Comment: No, I really meant $z_{x_5}$. All basic variables are increased by $30$ $(-1/6,1/6,0)$. The dot product of the basic variables by this last column is precisely  $z_{x_5}$.

Comment: ah okay then, thanks. so what about 3e please? ^-^ Is what I said right?

Comment: 3 e looks good!

Comment: Well that's not what my prof said, but what was said is equivalent to that. Clever. Thanks Kuifje ^-^